# Broadcasting Messages at High Frequency. Using HTTP POST or something else?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, broadcast, broadcasting

We're looking at speccing out a system which broadcasts small amounts of frequently changing data (using JSON or XML or something) to multiple recipients at a reasonably high frequency (our updates will be 1000s per second).

We were initially thinking of using HTTP POST to broadcast the data to each endpoint, maybe once every few seconds (the clients will vary as they're other people's webapps), but we're now wondering if there's a better way to hold up to the load/frequency we're hoping.  I imagine we'd need to version/timestamp the messages in some way at the very least.

We're using RabbitMQ for preparing all the things ready for sending and to choose what needs to go where (from a Django app, if that matters), but we can't get all of the endpoints to use a MQ.

The HTTP POST thing just doesn't seem quite right.  What else should we be looking in to?  Is this where things like node or socket.io or some of the new real time frameworks fit in?  We're happy to find the right expertise to help with this, just need steering the correct direction.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your preferred programming language for the servers and clients?  Seems like you could prototype something using Java and Netty.  Also, rather than "HTTP POST" , you could go cutting edge tech and use "WebSockets".

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do thousands of POSTs per second to multiple clients. You're going to introduce the HTTP overhead on your end pushing it out, and for all you know, you might end up flooding the server on the other end with POSTs that just swamp it.

Option 1: For clients that can't or won't read a queue, POSTS could work, but to avoid killing the server and all the HTTP overhead, could you bundle updates? Once every minute or two, take all the aggregate data and then post it to the client? This way, you don't have 60+ POST requests going to one client every minute or two for time and eternity. It'll help save on bandwidth as well, since you only send all the header info once with more data instead of sending all the header information and pieces of data.

Option 2: Have you thought about using a good 'ole socket connection? Either you open a socket to the client, or vice versa, and push the data over that? That avoids the overhead of HTTP and lets the client read at the rate data arrives. If the client no longer wants to receive data, they can just close the connection. It's on the arcane side, but it'd avoid completely killing the target server.

If you can get clients to read a MQ, set up a group just for them and make your life easier so you only have to deal with those that can't or won't read the queue instead of trying for a one size fits all solution.